# android hello world app help

Tags: java, android

i am learning android apps and i made this app and it doesnt work

```
  package com.android.test;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.Toast;

  public class HelloWorld extends Activity {
      /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.main);
          Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
          button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  Toast.makeText(HelloWorld.this, "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          });
      }
  }
```

but it doesnt work!!! please tell me what is wrong and help me to solve it!1

Comment: What exactly doesn't work here?  Can you post the exception you are getting from LogCat?

Comment: Please expand on "doesn't work." Does it crash? Hang? Doesn't look as you expected?

Comment: i get red line in :

Toast.makeText(HelloWorld.this, "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: How are you attempting to run it? This code should work.

Comment: @ninja - Are you having trouble compiling this or running it? What do you mean by "i get red line"?

Comment: Red line probably means the code is wrong. @ninja: hover the mouse on the code with red line, and it will show you what the error is, and probably a solution for it as well. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the toast line to as follows:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```